# While upgrading to Angular 13, installing @angular/localize@13.0.0 gives babel dependency error

Tags: angular, npm, babeljs

While upgrading to Angular 13, installing `npm i @angular/localize@13.0.0` gives following error -

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/core@7.8.6.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular/localize'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\we333\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-10T18_59_00_115Z-debug.log
```

Any idea how to fix it?

**Environment**

- Angular CLI 13.0.1

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk-experimental": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0"
}
```

Comment: When run at your project root, what does this print? `npm show @babel/core@7.8.6` and in case that errors: `npm config get registry`